# Why does copy paste keyframes paste keyframes additional to those I selected?

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

In the dopesheet I

- press `a` twice to deselect everything
- push `b` to lasso select
- select some keyframes from an object
- push `ctrl-c` to copy
- push `ctrl-v` to paste

But Blender pastes keyframes that weren't even highlighted! See the screenshot gif below.  How do I prevent this pelase?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Selected channels

As the tooltip suggests, when you paste from the buffer, the keyframes are pasted into the selected channels.

If no channel is selected, the keyframes are pasted into all the editable channels.

[image]

### Duplicate

In my opinion, this is the easiest way.

You can **duplicate** the keyframes (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) and move them by entering the number of frames or by moving the mouse.

### Include only selected objects

Alternatively, you can include only the channels related to the selected object.
[image]

or

### Protect channels

You can protect the other channels from editing:

1. Select the channel
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (*locked* / *unlocked*)
   [image]